# Display table in php from mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm doing a search engine, where after the student id is inserted in the text field, it will display the data about the student. I want to display it in the table form using the php code. But it doesn't work. Below is my code.

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>MrBool Development Article</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <form action="search.php" method="GET"> 
        <b>Enter Search Term:</b> 
        <input type="text" name="term" size="50"> 
        <input type="submit" value="Search"> 
    </form> 

    <?php 
        mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); 
        mysql_select_db("attendance_system"); 
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM studentAttendance WHERE student_stud_matric LIKE '%$_GET[term]%'"); 
        while ($ser = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
            echo "<table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Student Matric</th>
                            <th>Subject Name</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>                                        
                    <tbody>";   

            echo "<tr>
                    <td>".$ser[student_stud_matric]."</td>
                    <td>".$ser[course_course_code]."</td>                                       
                </tr>";

            echo "</tbody></table>";
        } 
    ?> 
    <hr> 
    <a href="index.php">Go Back</a> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: What means "doesn't work"? Any errors? Check for errors after every db statement. Stop using deprecated `mysql_*`API use `mysqli_*`or `PDO` with prepared statements

Comment: changing the `$ser[student_stud_matric]` to `$ser['student_stud_matric']` and `$ser[course_course_code]` to `$ser['course_course_code']` may solve the problem!!

Comment: The data comes out but not in the table form. Besides, it shows error that said: Notice: Use of undefined constant student_stud_matric - assumed 'student_stud_matric' in C:\wamp\www\searchengine\search.php on line 31 and Notice: Use of undefined constant course_course_code - assumed 'course_course_code' in C:\wamp\www\searchengine\search.php on line 32..
I still a new learner to this type of code.. Tq for the advise @Jens

Comment: You probably should move the table and thead outside of the wile loop. You also should not pass user input directly into your query this is how you get injected.

Comment: `mysql` extension is depricated. try to use `mysqli` instead. also use mysql_error(). like this.
`mysql_query("SELECT * FROM studentAttendance WHERE student_stud_matric LIKE '%$_GET[term]%'") or die(mysql_error());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DO not create table inside while loop it would be like this

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>MrBool Development Article</title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <form action="search.php" method="GET"> 
            <b>Enter Search Term:</b> 
            <input type="text" name="term" size="50"> 

            <input type="submit" value="Search"> 
        </form> 
        <?php
        mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
        mysql_select_db("attendance_system");
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM studentAttendance WHERE student_stud_matric LIKE '%$_GET[term]%'");
        ?>

        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Student Matric</th>
                    <th>Subject Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>                                        
            <tbody>
                <?php while ($ser = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $ser['student_stud_matric']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $ser['course_course_code'] ?></td>                                       
                    </tr>
                <?php }
                ?> 
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <hr> 
        <a href="index.php">Go Back</a> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Works well.. TQSM! @saty

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following with your `while` loop, and it's done. However, seriously consider avoiding from mostruous `mysql_*` :)

```
$table = "<table><thead><tr><th>Student Matric</th><th>Subject Name</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
while($ser = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $table .= "<tr><td>{$ser['student_stud_matric']}</td><td>{$ser['course_course_code']}</td></tr>";
}
$table .= "</tbody></table>";
echo $table;
```

Comment: may I ask, which part that I represent to use the mysql_*? I'm sorry, I'm still a new learner to this type of code T.T @someOne

Comment: @KrengKongkeng In your example code the `mysql_connect()`, `mysql_select_db()`, `mysql_query()`, `mysql_fetch_array()` all are started with the `mysql_*` :)

Comment: hooo that one.. alright.. thanks! @someOne